# how to query mongodb long fields?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, int64

Suppose I am creating a mongodb collection from pymongo in this way:

```
import pymongo
myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
#create db
mydb = myclient["query_int64"]
#mydb.command('create', 'timeseriesCollection', {"timeseries":{ 'timeField': 'timestamps', 'metaField': 'metadata'}})
validator = {
    "$jsonSchema": {
        "bsonType": "object",
        "required": ["timestamp", "value"],
        "properties": {
            "timestamp": {
                "bsonType": "long",
            },
            "value": {
                "bsonType": "double"
            },
        }
    }
}
res = mydb.command("collMod", "timeseriesCollection", validator=validator)
print(res)
mydb.timeseriesCollection.insert_one({"timestamp": 1688138933864487000, "value": 12.2})
mydb.timeseriesCollection.insert_one({"timestamp": 1688138933947443000, "value": 14.2})
```

From mongo compass I am trying to query on the timestamp field. I've tried both:

```
{"timestamp": {"$eq": 1688138933864487000}}
```

and

```
{"timestamp": 1688138933864487000}
```

but it's returning empty.

How to query int64 fields for equality, less than, great than and a combination of the last 2 in mongodb ?

Comment: Does a simple `find()` return anything? [Your query](https://mongoplayground.net/p/gAGFr_ewoIP) seems nothing wrong

Comment: Yes querying {} from mongo dB compass returns both entries, which mongodb compass is showing

Comment: Tried both in Mongo compass. It's returning the correct result. And it's working in Python too: `mydb.timeseriesCollection.find_one({"timestamp": 1688138933864487000})` result: `{'_id': ObjectId('65a95eeebf8cd9b8c9277374'), 'timestamp': 1688138933864487000, 'value': 12.2}`

Comment: In pymongo it's working for me as well. Could you please paste the exact string you are using in MongoDb Compass

Comment: I found a solution, check the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution: in mongo shell or in client GUI such as Mongodb Compass, the query returning results is:

```
{"timestamp": NumberLong("1688138933947443000")}
```

Being the type an `int64`.

In pymongo it is more straightforward:

```
mydb.timeseriesCollection.find_one({"timestamp": 1688138933864487000})
```